# i need to check every installed application and check if it is allowed to use mobile data connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hello eveyone i need to check every installed application on phone if it is allowed to use data mobile connection

with some help i have reached t filter all the application that uses internet connection and add them on a list now i need to check the applications that is allowed to use data mobile connection and i have a switch on my layout so i can check it true or false(depends if the app is allowed to use data mobile or not)

```
private boolean usesInternet(PackageInfo pInfo) {
    if(pInfo.requestedPermissions != null) {
        for(String i : pInfo.requestedPermissions)
            if(i.equals(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){
        return true;}
    }
    return false;
}

private List<AppList> getAllInstalledApps() {

    List<AppList> List = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    //bln = false;

    for(PackageInfo p : packs){

            if(usesInternet(p)){
                String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
                List.add(new AppList(appName, icon));
            }

    }

   /* for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false)) {
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            List.add(new AppList(appName, icon));

        }
    }*/
    return List;
}
```

filtering every app that use connection if it is allowed to use mobile data.
if yes change the value of a switch to true.

Comment: All apps on standard Android are allowed to use mobile data connections.

Comment: yes but if some of the applications has been disallowed of using the mobile data connection how can i filter them.

Comment: "if some of the applications has been disallowed of using the mobile data connection" -- this does not exist in standard Android. There is an option in some newer versions of Android that limit an app's use of mobile data in the background.

Comment: yeah that's will do the trick hwo can i limit an app's use of mobile data